# This page isn’t working Error in deploying my API on Azure and IIS ? while its correctly working on localhost

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc, webapi

how can I solve this error (405) related to deploying my web api to azure?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

405 errors are generally confusing Get and Post requests. Please try to use the Postman tool and use Post to request this api.

> This page isn’t working Error in deploying my API on Azure and IIS ? while its correctly working on localhost

According to your description, the problem should not be related to Azure App Service or IIS.

**General troubleshooting steps:**

1. Determine whether the home page can be accessed normally or the api that accepts Get requests.
2. If it can be accessed normally, then the request type of the interface may be wrong.
3. If that doesn't work, open EventViewer to view the logs. It is also possible to set [stdoutlogenabled=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-6.0).